# How to use a future without waiting for it?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

The following example is taken from a [C++ async tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/17/cpp-11-async-tutorial/):

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int twice(int m) { return 2 * m; }

int main() {
  std::vector<std::future<int>> futures;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { futures.push_back (std::async(twice, i)); }

  //retrive and print the value stored in the future
  for(auto &e : futures) { std::cout << e.get() << std::endl; }
  return 0;
}
```

How can I use the result of a `future` without waiting for it? Ie I would like to do something like this:

```
  int sum = 0;
  for(auto &e : futures) { sum += someLengthyCalculation(e.get()); }
```

I could pass a reference to the `future` to `someLengthyCalculation`, but at some point I have to call `get` to retrieve the value, thus I dont know how to write it without waiting for the first element being completed, before the next one can start summing.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `then` and `when_all` or `when_any` continuations?

Answer (score 4):

You are right that the current `future` library is not complete yet.  What we miss is a way to indicate 'when future x is ready, start operation f'.  Here's a nice [post about that](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/02/26/c17-i-see-a-monad-in-your-future/).

What you may want is a map/reduce implementation: upon each future's completion, you want to start adding it to the accumulator (reduce).

You can use a library for that - it's not very simple to build it yourself :).  One of the libraries that's gaining traction is RxCpp - and they have a [post on map/reduce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html).

Answer (score 1):

The design of futures lends itself to this kind of solution, where you create more futures representing the calculated values:

```
  std::vector<std::future<int>> calculated_futures;

  for (auto &e : futures) {
      calculated_futures.push_back(
          std::async([&e]{ return someLengthyCalculation(e.get()); })
      );
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for(auto &e : calculated_futures) { sum += e.get(); }
```

Comment: Maybe that is more of the answer OP is helped with... Hint: std::transform futures into calculated_futures to better express intent.